# How to insert expression matching the format?

Tags: programming, notebooks, style

I would like programmatically to insert/write an expression at the current insertion point, but matching the current format, such as font size and style, so that it looks like the user typed it. Default use of `NotebookWrite[]`, `NotebookApply[]` and `Paste[]` doesn't do this.

For instance if you change the colour in a text cell and press the paste button -> it will paste text in black colour, unlike typing that text yourself. How to avoid this?

Off course, one could set any specific style when using `Paste[Style[exp, Red]]`, but it is unknown here- it is the style at insertion. And the same for Font.